# MySQl SUM column content if the content is "1"

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query and I need to SUM the content of a column if the content contains the number 1,

This is what I have but the TotalFails returns 0

```
SELECT 
d.SeqNo,
d.SeqText,
h.UniqueID,
h.SeqID,
h.Room,
IF(h.Status = '1', SUM(h.Status), 0) AS TotalFails
FROM ".$SequenceNo_default." d
LEFT 
JOIN ".$Hist." h ON h.SeqID = d.SeqID 
WHERE  d.SeqActive = 1 AND DATE(CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE(   '".$_SESSION['StartDate']."') AND  DATE('".$_SESSION['EndDate']."')
GROUP BY h.Room
ORDER BY h.Status ASC
```

Can any one see where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is the data type of the `Status` field?

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding why you would (logically speaking) have the SUM inside the IF, and why you would group on a field from the right side of a LEFT JOIN. Given all that, I still can't see why you would be getting 0 for TotalFails on a result row that has status = 1. Perhaps it is the reserved word matter Sablefoste's answer is mentioning. Try delimiting all references with the ` character (i.e. `Status` becomes `\`Status\``)

Comment: You group by `Room`. One result row per room. Is this the unique key? Only one `UniqueID`, one `SeqID`, one `Status` per room? I must assume this, because you still access these fields after grouping by room, but then, maybe the query is just broken. (Anyway, `SeqID` *is* SequenceNo_default`s unique key; correct?)

Comment: Hi, I have just left the college, I will look at it when I get home later. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `Status` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) so you may want to change it to something else like `myStatus` in the statement above.

**Edit**

Based upon your updated question, I would rewrite your query as follows (again, avoiding the keyword `STATUS` by replacing `Status` with `myStatus`):

```
SELECT 
d.SeqNo,
d.SeqText,
h.UniqueID,
h.SeqID,
h.Room,
SUM(h.myStatus) AS TotalFails
FROM ".$SequenceNo_default." d
LEFT 
JOIN ".$Hist." h ON h.SeqID = d.SeqID 
WHERE  d.SeqActive = 1 AND DATE(CompStamp) BETWEEN DATE(   '".$_SESSION['StartDate']."') AND  DATE('".$_SESSION['EndDate']."')
GROUP BY h.Room, h.myStatus
ORDER BY h.myStatus ASC
```

As a separate side note, this should be a prepared query, rather than including the `$_SESSION` variable directly into the string.  `$_SESSION` is better than `$_POST` or `$_GET`, but for maintaining the code, this would be a good habit (for example, what if the code later changes to `$_POST`?).

Comment: @Uueerdo the data type is "int". I have tried SELECT IF(h.Status = '1', SUM(h.Status), 0) AS TotalFails provided by Sablefoste   but TotalFails returns 0. I know that some records have 1 in the Status column.

Comment: @Uueerdo I have edited the question and puy the complete query

Comment: `Status` is a keyword, but not a reserved one, so you can still use it for table and column names without a problem.